# SQL harvesine law to grab nearest coordinates question

Tags: php, laravel

in my app I want to show nearest places from map center coordinate, after looking for solutions I found a raw SQL query I could use in my laravel app:

This is my method:

```
$venues = Venue::select(DB::raw('*, ( 6367 * acos( cos( radians('.$latitude.') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('.$longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$latitude.') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance'))
    ->having('distance', '<', 25)
    ->orderBy('distance')
    ->get();
```

It is working perfectly but right here:

```
->having('distance', '<', 25)
```

I don't know what kind of measurement the 25 is, is it kilometers, miles, obviously it's not meters, anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

That constant 6367 looks like an approximation to the earth's radius in kilometers.
It looks like your units are kilometers.